# Subversion properties in windows explorer

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, windows-11

How can I see subversion properties (tortoiseSVN) in windows explorer? (for example user who blocked file or number of the revisions) I don't want to right click on file and go to subversion properties every time. I use windows 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before Windows Vista it was possible to show TortoiseSVN columns in folder's Explorer view, but not anymore. You have two options now:

- Use alternative to Windows Explorer. There is one called xplorer². This one still allows for custom columns (also known as extended file information).
- Use Check For Modifications from TSVN menu and check Unmodified option. You can move this menu item from TortoiseSVN submenu to main context menu, to reduce the time spent using it. Go to TortoiseSVN > Settings > General > Context Menu and check the appropriate option from the list.

You can also use `svn status` command from command prompt, but Check For Modification is this, only better.

Comment: Thank you. Do you recommend any free software?

Comment: @pio I don't really know. Try googling for "free explorer replacement" without the quotes. My workaround for this is to click Commit, to see what has changed, without actually committing anything. Files should not be blocked, and revision numbers are not important to me. Also, upvote the answers you find useful on the site. Accept those answers that answer your question. This is how StackOverflow works.